# fmtcount problem after polyglossia update

Tags: polyglossia, fmtcount

I'm seeing strange behaviour in a package (cooking-units) that internally uses fmtcount to convert numbers to their respective names. The same problem also occurs when using fmtcount directly.

I can't exactly pinpoint the date when this first happened, but I think I saw this after a recent update of polyglossia in early February.
It's a possibility that it's a problem in the fmtcount package, but that hasn't been touched since 2020, so I'm not sure of that.

This code ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
%works fine when using babel
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\begin{document}
a\numberstringnum{2} b
\end{document}
```

... produces an unwanted line break, when compiled with XeLaTeX and if polyglossia is used. It works fine when babel is used. I'm using MiKTeX on Windows.

Polyglossia output:

[image: polyglossia output]

Babel output:

[image: babel output]

Comment: load the language: \FCloadlang{ngerman}. As the documentation says, if you don't do this, it tries to detect in the document and "that may cause problems such as spurious spaces insertion before the first formatted number"

Comment: Thanks a lot @UlrikeFischer. I would have never figured this out, as I don't use this package directly in my code.
I'll forward this to the maintainer of the cooking-units package, but for the time being I can easily insert that in my main file.